# DBT SQL + Postgres set session variable using current date

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt

I am trying to set a variable I later use within a query to send some data as a csv to S3. I'd like to use the current timestamp as part of my filename, in DBT I have access to SQL, but can't quite crack how to make this happen.

My variable setting code, I know this doesn't look any good or work, this is what I'd like to achieve:

```
SET session data_output.filename = GETDATE()+"-attrs.csv";
```

Where I use this variable:

```
aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
    'table_name',
    current_setting('data_output.filename')::varchar,
    'us-east-1'
)
```

Expected output '2021-11-10-170423-attrs.csv' for my `data_output.filename`

Comment: Using the [COPY TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) sql command, you can simply insert `now()`or `current_timestamp(0)` in the statement like `COPY your_query TO your_absolute_path || current_timestamp(0) || '-attrs.csv'` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_config`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE):

```
SELECT set_config(
          'data_output.filename',
          current_date || '-attrs.csv',
          FALSE
       );
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Postgres, more of a MySQL man so I might be missing something obvious

Getting `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "current_date"`

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing comma.

Comment: Now getting this, `ERROR:  function set_config(unknown, text) does not exist`

Comment: Try: SELECT set_config(
          'session data_output.filename',
          current_date || '-attrs.csv', False
       );

Comment: I have finally fixed it. Sorry, I wrote that answer while I was AFK.